# POST request to Clevertap using GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, guzzle, clevertap

I am using Laravel 5.1 and Guzzlehttp 6.1 to make post request to clevertap.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['X-CleverTap-Account-Id' => '**********','X-CleverTap-Passcode'=>'*************8']]);



$result = $client->request('POST','https://api.clevertap.com/1/upload',["d"=>[
    "identity"=>"1189549",
      "ts"=>1419421212,
      "type"=>"profile",
      "profileData"=>[
        "Name"=>"Jack Montana",
        "Email"=>"jack@gmail.com",
        "Phone"=>"+14155551234",
        "Gender"=>"M",
        "Employed"=>"Y",
        "Education"=>"Graduate",
        "Married"=>"Y",
        "Age"=>28,
        "Customer Type"=>"Platinum",
      ]]]);
```

I am getting following Error.

> Client error: `POST https://api.clevertap.com/1/upload` resulted in a
>   `400 Bad Request` response: { "status" : "fail" , "error" : "Payload
>   is mandatory"}

Comment: HI, can you check the format again and post it . the second argument should be array of objects

Comment: right ..the second argument should be array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you sent the ID/Token in the header, it is mandatory to send the payload inside the body of the HTTP request.

Something like this:

```
$r = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', [ 'body' =>'raw data' ]);
```

This should return a 200 OK and do the necessary updates.

Comment: Right Jay but actual problem was that the second argument should be array of objects